# Working with the awk line matching pattern

Tags: awk

The tool `awk` has line pattern matching like

```
/pattern/ { statements; }
```

Is there any way to get the string of `pattern` as a variable, for use in `match` expressions etc?

Or even better, directly get:

- pattern matched text
- pattern matched length
- match groups if there are any `(groups)` in the pattern

within the `{statements}` block?

Comment: If you could post an example I could update my answer with output too :)

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use GNU awk and, instead of using `/pattern/` in the condition part, use  `match`  and its third argument `match(string, regexp [, array])` you get access to matched text, start index, length and the groups:

```
$ echo foobar | 
gawk 'match($0, /(fo*)(b.*)/, a) {
    print a[0],a[0,"start"],a[0,"length"]    # 0 index refers to whole matched text
    print a[2],a[2,"start"],a[2,"length"]    # 1, 2, etc. to matched groups
}'
foobar 1 6
bar 4 3
```

See  [GNU awk documentation for `match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) for more info.

Comment: Aha, *you can use match in the pattern-expression*, you don't have to use it in an `if` block inside! That's the clue I missed.

Comment: What do you think `b.?*` means in your regexp? No, it doesn't mean that :-).

Comment: I was a bit puzzled that it worked, kind of just left it there not expecting anyone to notice it so thanks for noticing. :D

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following ones.

1st: To get matching text `match` is BEST option.

```
awk 'match($0,/regex/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

2nd: To get length of matched string:

```
awk 'match($0,/regex/){print RLENGTH}'  Input_file
```

3rd: To get all matched patterns use `while` loop with match until match found in line and we should get all matched patterns.